# Elasticsearch Hosting for Beginners

Tags: elasticsearch, cloud-hosting

I am very new to the Elasticsearch. I have seen many tutorials and I have started implementing it into my new app on Localhost.

However, is it really so expensive to run Elasticsearch as a service once I decide to go public with my app? I saw prices around $50 per month. I know that is is incomparable, but I can run MySQL on my webserver for more economical price.

Is there a cheaper solution for Elasticsearch beginners? I would really like to start and if the project flies, then I would consider extending and improving the infrastructure.

Could I please have your opinion on the matter?

Thank you and best regards,
Jakub

Answer (score 0):

Our production site hosts the same data in both elasticsearch and postgres, and we pay half the price for elasticsearch. You can of course host it yourself to bring the price down. And here's some services lower than $50/mo:

- [Bonsai](https://addons.heroku.com/bonsai)
- [SearchBox](https://addons.heroku.com/searchbox)